# How to Use ARM Template `contentVersion`?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

The documentation on ARM templates does not show how to use *different* versions (at least that I can find). All I get from the document is that the `contentVersion` value in the `templateLink` and the `parameterLink` objects need to match the value in the linked template.

```
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
    "name": "linkedTemplate",
    "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
        "uri":"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.json",
        "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parametersLink": {
        "uri":"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.parameters.json",
        "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
    }
    }
  }
]
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#external-template-and-external-parameters

Someone opened an issue on GitHub to request additional information but I still didn't get a clear picture of how to use the version. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9402

Does anyone know of any examples of how to use different `contentVersion` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may misunderstand the usage of the `contentVersion` , the property is just used to document changes in your template and make sure you are using the correct template, it can be any value.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#template-format

[image]

For example, if the `contentVersion` in the template `https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.json` is `2.0.0.0`,

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "2.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": []
}
```

but you use `"contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"` like below,

```
 "templateLink": {
        "uri":"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.json",
        "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
    }
```

then you will get an error. It has been mentioned in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#external-template-and-external-parameters):

> You don't have to provide the `contentVersion` property for the template or parameters. If you don't provide a content version value, the current version of the template is deployed. If you provide a value for content version, it must match the version in the linked template; otherwise, the deployment fails with an error.

One day, if you make some changes to the target template, you can change the `contentVersion` to `3.0.0.0` to document the changes, etc. Or you do not change it. It all depends on you.